# How to set "anyone with the link" can edit permission on a Google Spreadsheet via API..PHP preferred

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have the following code for setting permissions on a file, how do I change this to anyone with link can edit permission?

```
function setPermissions($fileId, $email){
    $client2 = new \Google_Client();
    $client2->setApplicationName('Give permissions');
    $client2->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
    $client2->setAccessType('offline');
    $client2->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client2->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }
    $client2->setPrompt('select_account consent');
    $service2 = new Google_Service_Drive($client2);
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setEmailAddress($email);
    $newPermission->setType('user');
    $newPermission->setRole('writer');
    $service2->permissions->create($fileId, $newPermission);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal and your situation as follows.

- You want to create the permission with "anyone with link" as the writer using googleapis for php.
- You can get and put files using Drive API.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, please set `anyone` as `type` and remove `setEmailAddress($email)`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setEmailAddress($email);
$newPermission->setType('user');
$newPermission->setRole('writer');
```

To:

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('writer');
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)